# How to construct a hypothesis test for an accruing continuous variable over some time period?s

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

Supposing I had a data set that included a continuous variable evaluating the degradation of several cars' conditions. The condition is evaluated everyday for several months and the number of hours the car is driven each day is also logged. If someone asked me to tell them that the likelihood that this degradation surpassed some threshold is or is not dependent on the number of hours that the car was driven that day or the previous 10 days. How does one set up a hypothesis test for this? Can these even be considered independent events for statistics given that degradation is something that is accruing over time? My first guess was to just do a mixed model by converting the threshold to a binary variable for each record but that doesn't seem to take into account that the time it is driven occurs in a specific order.

It would also be nice to answer the same question in terms of whether the car was driven (yes/no) as opposed to just the number of hours.

Those who asked me to do this analysis are not statisticians (and neither am I). I don't think 'likelihood' is what they meant, rather just probability, but I am still not sure how to set up the test. I am using R, so if any suggestions or examples for that particular language are available, I would appreciate being pointed to them.